# regex count occurrences

Tags: python, regex

I am looking for a way to count the occurrences found in the string based on my regex. I used **findall()** and it returns a list but then the **len()** of the list is only 1? shouldn't the **len()** of the list be 2?

```
import re

string1 = r'Total $200.00 Total $900.00'
regex = r'(.*Total.*|.*Invoice.*|.*Amount.*)?(\s+?\$\s?[1-9]{1,10}.*(?: 
[.,]\d{3})*(?:[.,]\d{2})?)'
patt = re.findall(regex,string1)
print(patt)
print(len(patt))
```

Resut:

```
>     [('Total $200.00 Total', ' $900.00')]
>     1
```

not sure if my regex is causing it to miscalculate. I am looking to get the Total from a file but there are many combinations of this. 
Examples:

- Total $900.00
- Invoice Amt $500.00
- Total 800.00

etc.

I am looking to count this because there could be multiple invoice details in one file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, because that's a common misconception:

There is no need to match "all text up to the match" or "all the text after a match". You can drop those `.*` in your regex. Start with what you *actually* want to match.

```
import re

string1 = 'Total $200.00 Total $900.00'

amount_pattern = r'(?:Total|Amt|Invoice Amt|Others)[:\s]*\$([\d\.,]*\d)'
amount_expr = re.compile(amount_pattern, re.IGNORECASE)

amount_expr.findall(string1)
# -> ['200.00', '900.00']
```

`\$([\d\.,]*\d)` is a half-way reasonable approximation of prices (*"things that start with a `$` and then contain a bunch of digits and possibly dots and commas"*). The final `\d` makes sure we are not accidentally matching sentence punctuation. It might be good enough, but you know what data you are working with. Feel free to come up with a more specific sub-expression. Include an optional leading `-` if you expect to see negative amounts.

Comment: this definitely works better than my own, thanks Tomalak!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(\w*\s+\$\d+\.\d+)', string1)
['Total $200.00', 'Total $900.00']
```

The issue you are having is your regex has two capture groups so `re.findall` returns a tuple of those two matches. One tuple with two matches inside has a length of 1.